# Merge more then two query in one

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 working independently query, how I can but them as one

```
SELECT * , SUM(summa) AS papp9 FROM rent WHERE liige_id = 9 AND date > NOW()
SELECT * , SUM(summa) AS papp8 FROM rent WHERE liige_id = 8 AND date > NOW()
SELECT * , SUM(summa) AS papp7 FROM rent WHERE liige_id = 7 AND date > NOW()
```

first query results looks like that:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * , SUM(summa) AS papp FROM rent WHERE  date > NOW()
group by liige_id
```

Comment: This one almost works, but all SUM results with one name "papp", I think in My solution I need thous separately 
How it's right now example is here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/92bjzawrzl6rayf/Screenshot%202016-01-03%2022.57.04.png?dl=0

Comment: what is the problem in this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, SUM(summa) AS papp9 
FROM rent 
WHERE liige_id IN (7,8,9) 
AND date > NOW()
GROUP BY liige_id
```

Comment: This don't works - displaying all with one row and all SUM(summa) is add together